# Getting error for dom.load() while running test class

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am using 
        1. DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
        2. doc.Load(httpResponse);

these lines in one apex class to convert XML body to document.
while executing this class normally it will show output nothing will happen at that time. But when I am executing same class in test class at line no 2 m getting below error 
'System.XmlException: Failed to parse XML due to: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not P (position: START_DOCUMENT seen P... @1:1)'

Can anyone please help in same problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just remember callouts not work in test. So it seems your httpResponse is empty. You can either not run test on a callout block using Test.isRunningTest() or fake a response and use it when running test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added fake response in my code.and also I used Test.isrunningtest() method. so its giving me only 61% code coverage. And there are no chances to increase its coverage as its not loading xml to dom instance. Is there any replacement method to load xml body to doc?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. If you created fake response it should be the xml itself. Can you please add relevant code in your question.

Comment: I have done with this by using Organization-Wide Email Addresses. Thanks a lot